# Disable Right on .aspx page but enable on Hyperlink

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

Is it possible to disable right click on webpage but enable right click on Hyperlink(means on any files) in same page.

I know that I can disable right click but on hyperlink if possible please share the code, **purpose of disable R/C is to disable Refresh**.

Thanks

Comment: You may be better placed getting your app/site to work correctly and support browser refreshing. Trust me, you wont block a user refreshing the page in all browsers, devices, mediums...Let the web behave as it was intended and support page reloads.

Answer (score 0):

Use `OnClientClick` to return false as below-

`<asp:button ID="btninsert" runat="server" text="Button" OnClientClick="return false;" />`

For more detail refer:
[How to avoid page refresh after button click event in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21325211/how-to-avoid-page-refresh-after-button-click-event-in-asp-net)

[Disable page refresh after button click ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25534985/disable-page-refresh-after-button-click-asp-net)

Comment: Thanks for reply soon but code not sufficient for me Actually i am binding  n number of data into grid view and there is one check in grid view header based on this check box i am getting Submitted by clicking on button that is outside of grid view while pressing F5 or Right click Refresh it is getting duplicated same value so  i want to restrict them