# stop reload page in asp.net after button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel5" runat="server" >
</asp:Panel>

    <asp:Panel ID="Panel6" runat="server" >
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel ID="Panel7" runat="server" >
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="addButton" Text="Add More"  OnClick="btnMore_click" AutoPostBack ="false" style="margin-left: 877px" Width="84px"/>
```

as above code , I have three asp panel for each button click ,visible one panel by btnMore_click function .

```
 protected void btnMore_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int count = this.Controls;

        if(count == 1)
        {
            medPanel5.Visible = true;
            this.Controls++;
        }
        if (count == 2)
        {
            medPanel6.Visible = true;
            this.Controls++;
        }
        if (count == 3)
        {
            medPanel7.Visible = true;
            this.Controls++;
        }
    }
```

but currently , when I click button one set visible true . I do not have any issues with it .
but I face  page reload , each and every time I need to scroll  down to click add more button . is there amy way to stop page reload here ?

Comment: You can find usefull information here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25534985/disable-page-refresh-after-button-click-asp-net

Comment: <asp:updatepanel runat="server">
 <ContentTemplate>
 <asp:button id="button1" runat="server" Text="clickme" onclick="function" />
 </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:updatepanel> i used the same code to use asp:updatepanel but still reloading  do i need to change asp:panel as well ?

Comment: You have to add some client code (javascript) for this to work.

Comment: thanks bro finally understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is server side button. ON click of this if you have anything processing on server side than page will post back. Use Ajax if you don't want page post back.

you can use Use Update Panel or Callback too.

Comment: can you please give me any example link to refer ?
i refer to is ispostback =flase but not worked .

Comment: I used clientclick return flase not worked bro

Comment: @xyz clientclick return false only works for java script code. After this your code may not be submitted to server. You can refer example shared by Timur in the comment.

Comment: share your complete code. aspx and aspx.cs file code.

Comment: That's not how you share code here. Please edit your initial post

Comment: i understood it bro thanks for it 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68053152/changing-server-side-code-to-script-not-working but as i am new to this i was unable to convert to script . can you plz have a  look on it ? it is big help to me