# changing server side code to script not working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

my button click server code .This code i have implemented after button click show panel details one by one .

```
 protected int NumberOfControls
    {
        get { return (int)ViewState["NumControls"]; }
        set { ViewState["NumControls"] = value; }
    }
       protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.NumberOfControls = 1;
    }

protected void btnMedMore_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int count = this.NumberOfControls;

        if(count == 1)
        {
            medPanel1.Visible = true;
            this.NumberOfControls++;
        }
        if (count == 2)
        {
            medPanel2.Visible = true;
            this.NumberOfControls++;
        }
        if (count == 3)
        {
            medPanel3.Visible = true;
            this.NumberOfControls++;
        }
        if (count == 4)
        {
            medPanel4.Visible = true;
            this.NumberOfControls++;
        }
        if (count == 5)
        {
            medPanel5.Visible = true;
            this.NumberOfControls++;
        }
        if (count == 6)
        {
            medPanel6.Visible = true;
            this.NumberOfControls++;
        }
        if (count == 7)
        {
            medPanel7.Visible = true;
            this.NumberOfControls++;
        }
        if (count == 8)
        {
            medPanel8.Visible = true;
            addmoreButton.Enabled = false;
            this.NumberOfControls++;
        }
    }
```

my script code . as per server side code it is reloading again and again so I planned to use script to avoid it .
so i have added a img button and script to that /

```
 private void AddMeScript(System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image img)
    {
        int count = this.NumberOfControls;

        // Script for checkbox MyNotes
        string script = "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>\n";
        script += "function myAppts()\n{\n";
        script += "\t" + "if (" + count == 1 + ")\n\t{\n\t\t";
        script += medPanel1.ClientID + ".style.display='';\n\t\t";
        script += this.NumberOfControls++ ;
        script += "\n\t}\n\tif (" + count == 2 + ")\n\t{\n\t\t";
        script += medPanel2.ClientID + ".style.display='';\n\t\t";
        script += this.NumberOfControls++;
        script += "\n\t}\n\tif (" + count == 3 + ")\n\t{\n\t\t";
        script += medPanel3.ClientID + ".style.display='';\n\t\t";
        script += this.NumberOfControls++;
        script += "\n\t}\n\tif (" + count == 4 + ")\n\t{\n\t\t";
        script += medPanel4.ClientID + ".style.display='';\n\t\t";
        script += this.NumberOfControls++;
        script += "\n\t}\n\tif (" + count == 5 + ")\n\t{\n\t\t";
        script += medPanel6.ClientID + ".style.display='';\n\t\t";
        script += this.NumberOfControls++;
        script += "\n\t}\n\tif (" + count == 6 + ")\n\t{\n\t\t";
        script += medPanel6.ClientID + ".style.display='';\n\t\t";
        script += this.NumberOfControls++;
        script += "\n\t}\n\tif (" + count == 7 + ")\n\t{\n\t\t";
        script += medPanel7.ClientID + ".style.display='';\n\t\t";
        script += this.NumberOfControls++;
        script += "\n\t}\n\tif (" + count == 8 + ")\n\t{\n\t\t";
        script += medPanel8.ClientID + ".style.display='';\n\t\t";
        script += this.NumberOfControls++;

        script += "\n}\n</script>";
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "myAppts", script);
        img.Attributes.Add("onclick", "myAppts()");
    }
```

it is not increase NumberOfControls ? can anyone help me on it ?

Comment: Please share your complete code. Just sharing methods will not work.

Comment: stackover  not allowing me as i have so many (2999) line bro

Comment: i have edited the qus with all the method using to this function

Answer (score 1):

Your AddMeScript should read more like this if understanding you correctly

```
private void AddMeScript(System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image img)
{
            // Script for checkbox MyNotes
        string script = "<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>\n";
        script += "var count = " + this.NumberOfControls + ";\n";
        script += "function myAppts()\n{\n";
        script += "\t" + "if (count == " + this.NumberOfControls++ + ")\n\t{\n\t\t";
        script += medPanel1.ClientID + ".style.display='';\n\t\t";
        script += "count++;\n\t}\n";
        script += "\t" + "if (count == " + this.NumberOfControls++ + ")\n\t{\n\t\t";
        script += medPanel2.ClientID + ".style.display='';\n\t\t";
        script += "count++;\n\t}\n";
        script += "\t" + "if (count == " + this.NumberOfControls++ + ")\n\t{\n\t\t";
        script += medPanel3.ClientID + ".style.display='';\n\t\t";
        script += "count++;\n\t}\n";
        script += "\t" + "if (count == " + this.NumberOfControls++ + ")\n\t{\n\t\t";
        script += medPanel4.ClientID + ".style.display='';\n\t\t";
        script += "count++;\n\t}\n";
        script += "\t" + "if (count == " + this.NumberOfControls++ + ")\n\t{\n\t\t";
        script += medPanel5.ClientID + ".style.display='';\n\t\t";
        script += "count++;\n\t}\n";
        script += "\t" + "if (count == " + this.NumberOfControls++ + ")\n\t{\n\t\t";
        script += medPanel6.ClientID + ".style.display='';\n\t\t";
        script += "count++;\n\t}\n";
        script += "\t" + "if (count == " + this.NumberOfControls++ + ")\n\t{\n\t\t";
        script += medPanel7.ClientID + ".style.display='';\n\t\t";
        script += "count++;\n\t}\n";
        script += "\t" + "if (count == " + this.NumberOfControls++ + ")\n\t{\n\t\t";
        script += medPanel8.ClientID + ".style.display='';\n\t\t";
        script += "count++;\n\t}\n";
        script += "}";

        script += "\n</script>";
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "myAppts", script);
        img.Attributes.Add("onclick", "myAppts()");
}
```

it is commonly overlooked writing server code as though it is part of the client code when writing client code on the server side. This code block fixes your issue by putting variable `count` on the client side and changing   lines that were trying to add server code to client script like `script += this.NumberOfControls++ ;`

Comment: I think it will be better if you add some code to your answer so it will be more clear