# Calling Javascript function on button click event in web forms asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to do simple speech recognition using p5 library.

Why the OnClientClick method is not recognizing/returning the resulted speech.
Here is my form code

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Button ID="iBtnTest" runat="server" OnClientClick="go()" Text="Listen" />
    <!-- <input type="button" onclick="go()" value="Listen" -->
</form>
```

and my javascript code is like this:

```
 let handle = new p5.SpeechRec();
 handle.onResult = () => { alert(handle.resultString) }       
 function go() { handle.start(); }
```

i have included all the libraries properly and the above code works if i toggle between the simple input which i have commented out.

What am i doing wrong? If this question has already been answered then please give me a link.
Thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add ***return methodName()*** within OnClientClick.

See this and change your JavaScript function as it is.

[calling javascript function on OnClientClick event of a Submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979120/calling-javascript-function-on-onclientclick-event-of-a-submit-button)