# printing the contents of the div ta using link button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

I have the following code on my page to print the contents of the div tag:

```
function PrintDiv() {
            document.getElementById('<%=lblDateTime.ClientID %>').style.display = "block";
             document.getElementById('<%=lblDateTime.ClientID %>').innerHTML = new Date().toLocaleString();

            var contents = document.getElementById("dvContents").innerHTML;
            var frame1 = document.createElement('iframe');
            frame1.name = "frame1";
            frame1.style.position = "absolute";
            frame1.style.top = "-1000000px";
            document.body.appendChild(frame1);
            var frameDoc = (frame1.contentWindow) ? frame1.contentWindow : (frame1.contentDocument.document) ? frame1.contentDocument.document : frame1.contentDocument;
            frameDoc.document.open();
            frameDoc.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');
            frameDoc.document.write('</head><body>');
            frameDoc.document.write(contents);
            frameDoc.document.write('</body></html>');
            frameDoc.document.close();
            setTimeout(function () {
                window.frames["frame1"].focus();
                window.frames["frame1"].print();
                document.body.removeChild(frame1);
            }, 500);
            return false;
        }
```

I want to invoke this printing on the click of the LinkButton instead of the click of <input type="button". Can I invoke the above print function on the click of the linkbutton rather than <input type=button . Below is my link button:

```
<asp:LinkButton Width="130px" Height="50px" ID="print" CssClass="btns" runat="server" OnClientClick="printDiv();" >Print</asp:LinkButton>
```

This is the content that I am trying to print:

```
<div>
This is a test  
</div>
```

This is the input button that I am using right now:

```
  <input type="button" class="btns"  runat="server" onclick="PrintDiv();" value="Print" />
```

As soon as I click on the <input type=button, the print function is invoked, but if I replace the <input type button with linkbutton, print function is not invoked.
any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: A LinkButton will trigger a PostBack. The button does not.

Comment: See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979120/calling-javascript-function-on-onclientclick-event-of-a-submit-button

Comment: is that why the javascript is not invoked? I invoked javascript several times before on link button. I just use OnClientClick=   and name of the javascript function.

Comment: Thanks, link button is working with this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979120/calling-javascript-function-on-onclientclick-event-of-a-submit-button

Comment: `OnClientClick="printDiv(); return false;"` will do the trick

Comment: Yes, this worked!